# Настройка action в форме для удаления записи

Tags: php, url, laravel

Всем привет. Возможно ли в `Form::open()` передать такие параметры, чтобы получился нужный *URL*? Я хочу сделать форму для отправки `id` на удаление записи. Я знаю, что можно в массиве передать  `'url' =>` но очень не хочется этого делать. Есть ли возможность сделать это через `'route' =>` или `'action' =>`?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Нужно сделать так

```
Form::open(['route' => ['r.destroy', $model->id], 'role' => 'form']
```